# Bcm43142 driver wifi open-suse

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, opensuse, broadcom

i have a problem with my wifi that isn't working on opensuse tumbleweed, when i open the NetworkManager, i see only ethenet interface :

```
0d:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

I have tried to install the `broadcom-wl` from zypper but it return an error in installation.

Answer (score 1):

Choose and add the Packman mirrors from **[here](https://en.opensuse.org//Additional_package_repositories#Packman)**:

To find out if already have Packman , open the terminal and type :

```
zypper lr -d
```

**e,g : Open-suse Leap 42.1**

Add pacman mirrors using the following command:

```
zypper ar -f -n packman http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Leap_42.1/ packman
```

To install the Broadcom Drivers, you need 2 packages:

`broadcom-wl` and `broadcom-wl-kmp` , it can be installed using one of the following commands:

```
zypper in broadcom-wl broadcom-wl-kmp-desktop
```

or

```
zypper in broadcom-wl broadcom-wl-kmp-default
```

or

```
zypper in broadcom-wl broadcom-wl-kmp-pae
```

Finally reboot your system .

**open-suse Tumbleweed**:

Add the Pacman mirror:

```
zypper ar -f -n packman http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/ packman
```

Install the driver:

```
zypper in broadcom-wl broadcom-wl-kmp-desktop
```

Reboot